# RecyclerView - ItemAnimator -> animateChange does not work properly?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get my head around the `ItemAnimator` class to be used if I want to animate the content of my `RecyclerView`.

Here my problem is very specific : I don't understand how the **change animation** works and I am not using move / add / delete animations: only change.

I've been looking to examples like the `BaseItemAnimator` of [this project](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) to see how it uses the `SimpleItemAnimator` as defined inside the **android support library**.

When the change animation is actually run after the method `runPendingAnimation()` is called [I can see](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators/blob/master/animators/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/recyclerview/animators/BaseItemAnimator.java#L351) that there is two `ViewHolders` containing the same view but not exactly (I checked, different IDs, but SAME content!) and both are animated with translation and alpha values.
I tried adding my own animation, like scale to see if I get it, but no because some time it works some time it does not. I just don't understand how the `RecyclerView` uses his view holders when there are such animations.

Can anyone tell me how I should be using these view holders so that my own animations are played properly everytime ? I'd like to run an animation that resize the cell.

Thanks !

PS:

1. I use the `Adapater#notifyItemChange(position)` method to trigger the animation
2. I trigger the animation when the `RecyclerView` is not being scrolled
3. I use `setSupportsChangeAnimations(true)` so that change animations are triggered

---

### EDIT 1

I'd like to show the code where I attempt to add my own animations alongside the the already existing animations. Remember, we are inside `runPendingChanges()`.

```
if (changesPending) {
            final List<CustomChangeInfo> changes = new ArrayList<>(this.mPendingChangesCustom.size());
            changes.addAll(this.mPendingChangesCustom);
            this.mPendingChangesCustom.clear();
            final Runnable changer = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (final CustomChangeInfo customChangeInfo : changes) {
                        final ChangeInfo changeInfo = customChangeInfo.changeInfo;

                        final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = changeInfo.oldHolder;
                        final View oldView = holder == null ? null : holder.itemView;
                        final RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder = changeInfo.newHolder;
                        final View newView = newHolder != null ? newHolder.itemView : null;
                        if (oldView != null) {
                            mChangeAnimations.add(changeInfo.oldHolder);
                            final ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat oldViewAnim =
                                    ViewCompat.animate(oldView).setDuration(2500);
                            oldViewAnim.scaleX(1.5f).scaleY(1.5f);
                            oldViewAnim.translationX(changeInfo.toX - changeInfo.fromX);
                            oldViewAnim.translationY(changeInfo.toY - changeInfo.fromY);
                            oldViewAnim.alpha(1).setListener(new VpaListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override public void onAnimationStart(View view) {
                                    dispatchChangeStarting(changeInfo.oldHolder, true);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Start Old View id = " + view.getId());
                                }

                                @Override public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "End Old View id = " + oldView.getId());
                                    oldViewAnim.setListener(null);
                                    ViewCompat.setAlpha(view, 1);
                                    ViewCompat.setTranslationX(view, 0);
                                    ViewCompat.setTranslationY(view, 0);
                                    ViewCompat.setScaleX(view, 1f);
                                    ViewCompat.setScaleY(view, 1f);
                                    dispatchChangeFinished(changeInfo.oldHolder, true);
                                    mChangeAnimations.remove(changeInfo.oldHolder);
                                    dispatchFinishedWhenDone();
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                        if (newView != null) {
                            mChangeAnimations.add(changeInfo.newHolder);
                            final ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat newViewAnimation = ViewCompat.animate(newView);
                            newViewAnimation.translationX(0).translationY(0).setDuration(2500)
                                    .scaleX(1.5f).scaleY(1.5f)
                                    .alpha(1).setListener(new VpaListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override public void onAnimationStart(View view) {
                                    dispatchChangeStarting(changeInfo.newHolder, false);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Start New View id = " + view.getId());
                                }

                                @Override public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "End New View id = " + newView.getId());
                                    newViewAnimation.setListener(null);
                                    ViewCompat.setAlpha(newView, 1);
                                    ViewCompat.setTranslationX(newView, 0);
                                    ViewCompat.setTranslationY(newView, 0);
                                    ViewCompat.setScaleX(newView, 1f);
                                    ViewCompat.setScaleY(newView, 1f);
                                    dispatchChangeFinished(changeInfo.newHolder, false);
                                    mChangeAnimations.remove(changeInfo.newHolder);
                                    dispatchFinishedWhenDone();
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

As you see I added some log to check the IDs to see if we're working on different views here and it is indeed the case !

The results are inconsistent : 
 1. some time I can see two views scaling, sometime only one
 2. some time it's another cell that was scaled (when I scroll after the animations)
 3. some time no animations are run...